# Connecting myo to windows phone 8.1 Stream Socket

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-phone-8.1, myo

I am trying to connect the Myo armband to a windows phone 8.1 app with no success so far, and because there is no sdk provided from thalmic labs for windows phone developers I am trying to achieve this vis stream socket.
this is the connection methode :

```
private async void myocom(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        PeerFinder.AlternateIdentities["Bluetooth:Paired"] = "";
        var pairedDevices = await PeerFinder.FindAllPeersAsync();
        if (pairedDevices.Count == 0)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("No paired devices were found.");

        }
        foreach (var pairedDevice in pairedDevices)
        {


            if (pairedDevice.DisplayName == "My Myo")
            {
                var m_HostName = pairedDevice.HostName;
                MessageDialog msgbox4 = new MessageDialog("" + m_HostName);
                await msgbox4.ShowAsync();

                try
                {
                    StreamSocket socket = new StreamSocket();
                    await socket.ConnectAsync(m_HostName, "1");
                    MessageDialog msgbox5 = new MessageDialog("ok");
                    await msgbox5.ShowAsync();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageDialog msgbox3 = new MessageDialog(ex.Message);
                    await msgbox3.ShowAsync();
                }
                break;
            }


        }
```

when runnin this i get "Value does not fall within the expected range" and this error message :

```
'App10.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.NI.DLL'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
```

Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.ni.dll

by this point I am very desperate, So thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I founded this solution based on creating async Task for connection or another solution - add to appxmanifest next data

```
<Capabilities>
    <m2:DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth.rfcomm">
      <m2:Device Id="any">
        <m2:Function Type="serviceId:00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB" />
      </m2:Device>
    </m2:DeviceCapability>
  </Capabilities>
```